# Using value from other rows in Pandas dataframe using np.where

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am looking to add a new column to a dataframe which takes a value from a column on the next row, if certain conditions are met.

```
df_psd['f2'] = np.where((df_psd['freq'] != 19.7403), df_psd.iloc[df_psd['index']+1,4], np.nan)
```

I'm trying to use `np.where` instead of iterating through rows as the dataframes are very large (>2.5M rows). The last row in the dataframe will always have a value for 'freq' of 19.7403. There is a column called 'index' in the dataframe which is equal to the row number.

When I try to run the above line I get an index error.

> IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds

If I remove the +1 from the `.iloc` method then it runs but returns the value from the same line rather than the next line. The number 4 in the '.iloc' method is correct as, without the +1, it returns a value from the correct column only from the wrong row.

I have tried adding another condition to the np.where term to check that it is not approaching the end of the dataframe, such as given below, but it still throws the same error.

```
df_psd['f2'] = np.where((df_psd['freq'] != 19.7403) & (df_psd['index'] < (len(df_psd)-1)), df_psd.iloc[df_psd['index']+1,4], np.nan)
```

If I change the return term to only return the index then I can see that it is returning np.nan for the correct rows (i.e. the conditions are working correctly) and have checked that this is the case for the last row in the dataframe.

I've tried looking for similar questions on Stack Overflow and have read the documentation but can't figure out why this is giving me an index error. Any advice would be a great help.

Comment: Please share sample data and expected output.

Comment: Are you looking for [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas-dataframe-shift)?

Comment: @HenryYik I don't think so. The dataframe includes data from multiple sensors over multiple time series. The highest frequency ('freq') recorded by each sensor is always 19.7403. If I just shifted the column down then it wouldn't account for this. Maybe the simplest thing would be to shift the column down and then use np.where to change values to np.nan where needed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, as suggested by @HenryYik, was to do this over two lines.

```
df_psd['f2'] = df_psd['freq'].shift(-1)
df_psd['f2'] = np.where((df_psd['freq'] == 19.7403), np.nan, df_psd['f2'])
```

The first line creates the new column by creating a shifted copy of the old column. The second line then use np.where to apply the appropriate conditions.

Thank you!

Comment: You could have passed `df_psd["freq"].shift(-1)` directly in `np.where`. Dont have to assign it as a new column first.

Comment: Thanks @HenryYik, I actually wanted to have both values on each row but otherwise what you've suggested would have been more efficient.